# Processing data incrementally

Tags: java, loops, process, classification, weka

I am currently developing a system for discovering associations formed through using Wekas machine learning suite and classifiers. My main problem was that the amount of memory used up when building classifier was more than my machine could allocate causing it to fail and everything to grind to a halt. I thought i had discovered that by using an updatable version of a Naivebayes this would allow me to incrementally add the data to the classifier and i could set a capacity variable for the reader, however i keep getting the very same issues i thought i had solved! The code and stack trace can be found below. Looking for any explanation as all questions/examples have been checked to no avail.

```
package model;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayesUpdateable;
import weka.core.Instance;
import weka.core.converters.ArffLoader;
import weka.core.converters.ArffLoader.ArffReader;

import java.io.File;

public class Naivebayes {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

String [] bayoptions = new String []{"-O"};

NaiveBayesUpdateable bayesins = new NaiveBayesUpdateable();
bayesins.setOptions(bayoptions);
bayesins.setDisplayModelInOldFormat(true);

        BufferedReader read = 
new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/GinoRondelli/workspace/Movies/src/data/200TagsBroo.arff"));

ArffReader  load = new ArffReader(read, 5000);
Instances naive = load.getStructure();
naive.setClassIndex(naive.numAttributes()-198);
Instance current;
while ((current = load.readInstance(naive)) != null){
        naive.add(current);
    }   
  bayesins.buildClassifier(naive);
 System.out.println(bayesins);  
 }
}
```

And the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at weka.estimators.DiscreteEstimator.<init>(DiscreteEstimator.java:59)
at weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes.buildClassifier(NaiveBayes.java:298)
at model.Naivebayes.main(Naivebayes.java:39)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is not the problem but just as a very basic check, do you have a reasonable -Xmx on the command line...?  Do not exceed your computer's ram (As a guideline leave the OS some ram too--you do NOT want java swapping), but the default is set really low so it's worth asking.

Anyway, It all depends on how your library is created.  It looks like you are adding data incrementally but I'm pretty sure the library is just accumulating it.  It looks like that's what you are doing--adding each load to naïve, so eventually it will run out of memory (assuming the semantics of the library aren't misleading)

If you don't need all the loads in your naïve then you might look for a flush or remove.  If you do need all the loads (and IF that's where all your memory is going) then you just will need more machine memory and a bigger -Xmx.

The best way to figure out where your memory is going is a Profiler.  It will tell you what object type is using the most memory and you can watch how much more is needed with each iteration.

Comment: Yeah i've got it set to 4GB -Xmx and have tried as high as 6, the really strange thing is that the file size is only actually 6MB which has totally thrown me for the last part

Comment: Then try clearing out naïve each iteration--or if you need them all at once then get a bigger machine (or a more efficient library)

Comment: Let me be more specific.  When processing a batch, only add a given number to naïve before calling  bayesins.buildClassifier(naive);, then clear naïve and grab the next bunch.  Currently it looks like you are just adding one at a time, but still adding them all--or am I missing something?